# Pandas - Merge on columns containing a few null values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frames - cities and stadiums. I want to merge them

```
cities
     Name   Stadium
0     c1      a
1     c2     NaN
2     c3     NaN
3     c4      b

stadiums
      Name     Capacity Type Col4 Col5
0       a        1       1    1     4
1       b        3       2    2     5
2       c        3       1    1     6

Output:
     Name   Stadium Capacity Type
0     c1      a       1       1
1     c2     NaN     NaN     NaN
2     c3     NaN     NaN     NaN
3     c4      b       3       2
```

When I merge them with one the following statements, I get additional rows:

```
cities = pd.merge(cities,stadiums[['Name','Capacity','Type']],left_on='Stadium',right_on='name',how='left')

cities = pd.merge(cities,stadiums[['Name','Capacity','Type']],left_on='Stadium',right_on='name',how='outer')
```

How do I merge these dataframes?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're performing an outer merge (`how='outer'`), which means all the rows from both dataframes are included in the output.  If you just want to match on the rows from the `cities` dataframe, try `how='left'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`outer` to `left`

```
cities = pd.merge(cities,stadiums[['Name','Capacity','Type']],left_on='Stadium',right_on='Name',how='left')
cities
Out[157]: 
  Name_x Stadium Name_y  Capacity  Type
0     c1       a      a       1.0   1.0
1     c2     NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN
2     c3     NaN    NaN       NaN   NaN
3     c4       b      b       3.0   2.0
```

Comment: @Shankze you have duplicated in merge keys , try to remove them before merge